# How can I point /dev/random to /dev/urandom

Tags: linux

I have a server that cannot generate enough entropy to support `/dev/random`. The particular piece of software having problems can't be configured to use `/dev/urandom`.

I tried moving `/dev/random` to `/dev/realrandom` and symlinking `/dev/random` to `/dev/urandom`, but `lsof /dev/realrandom` still shows processes using it.

In [Does 'urandom' share the same entropy of 'random'?](https://superuser.com/questions/150988/does-urandom-share-the-same-entropy-of-random), the suggestion is to use `mknod /dev/random 1 9`. Will this hold across restarts? Should I be using udev somehow?

Comment: I'd rather you didn't modify the question to suit the answers. I am not asking how to increase entropy.

Answer (score 19):

All you need to do is to create something like `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-disable-random-entropy-estimation.rules` with the following contents:

```
# /etc/udev/rules.d/70-disable-random-entropy-estimation.rules
# Disables /dev/random entropy estimation (it's mostly snake oil anyway).
#
# udevd will warn that the kernel-provided name 'random' and NAME= 'eerandom'
# disagree.  You can ignore this warning.

# Use /dev/eerandom instead of /dev/random for the entropy-estimating RNG.
KERNEL=="random", NAME="eerandom"

# Remove any existing /dev/random, then create symlink /dev/random pointing to
# /dev/urandom
KERNEL=="urandom", PROGRAM+="/bin/rm -f /dev/random", SYMLINK+="random"
```

Comment: +1 for actually answering the flipping question.

Comment: The first part doesn't seem to work in ubuntu 16.04, got error: `systemd-udevd[818]: NAME="eerandom" ignored, kernel device nodes can not be renamed; please fix it in /etc/udev/rules.d/70-disable-random-entropy-estimation.rules:8`

Answer (score 7):

You should consider [adding more entropy](http://www.vanheusden.com/Linux/#security) rather than compromising your system.

Comment: I have neither physical access to these systems to add hardware to increase entropy nor permanent shell access to apply kernel patches when it is updated. Are there other options to legitimately increase entropy?

Comment: None of those entropy daemons are kernel patches.

Comment: How is something like timer entropy daemon better for randomness than whatever urandom uses? I don't have a sound card or video device attached, so the other two listed there will not help.

Comment: urandom uses a mathematical formula to generate the next random value whenever real entropy isn't available. This mathematical formula, although seemingly random, *is* deterministic. Even a small bit of actual entropy is better than nothing.

Comment: From what I understand, urandom still uses entropy if it is available. I am willing to accept the relatively minuscule risk of using a not so random number when there is low entropy available with the trade-off being that the system responds more reliably. Adding entropy to the pool using a daemon is not a bad idea, but it is still possible to run out and that is what I want to avoid.

Comment: "`relatively minuscule risk of using a not so random number`"... Sigh... There are so many things wrong with this statement.

Comment: Use of /dev/urandom is perfectly fine. Blocking /dev/random was a bad idea. Here's a detailed explanation: http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/ - also, adding time to the entropy pool is probably way worse than the heading algorithm used by urandom

Comment: Interestingly none of these posts about adding more entropy suggest haveged as a solution - it's a daemon that feeds quality entropy to /dev/random so that it never runs out.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams /dev/random uses a pseudo-random number generator - the SAME ONE AS URANDOM. The random number pools are the same. The difference is that random GUESSES about how much entropy is left. Please do everyone a favor and read the link that posted

Answer (score 1):

I've used [egd](http://egd.sourceforge.net/) to solve this problem.  I'm betting you're using this with `gpg`.  I needed to compile gpg from source to get it to work with egd, but once I did it worked very well.

Another suggestion: [Sign up for an account here](http://random.irb.hr/) and download a gob of random numbers.  I think you can add entropy with a simple `cat file_with_random_numbers > /dev/random`.  There is also a utility on that site called `qrand` (needs to be compiled IIRC) that will download from the service and seed your /dev/random for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a proprietary program that is reading directly from the device, so I don't think EGD would work.

Comment: @ultra it's not really a good idea to get entropy from an unknown source like that. One of the key aspects you are after in the local entropy is that it is also unique. Getting it from an unknown source over a network means it may be logged, intercepted, or copied by someone else thus negating its value.

Comment: Not for super high security needs, of course not.  It certainly isn't best practice.  However, another secure source of random numbers could be gathered elsewhere and securely uploaded to feed the entropy.  Record 10 minutes of TV static off of an analog TV or VCR, upload the resultant .wav file to server (securely) and feed it to /dev/random.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a symlink

```
ln -s /dev/urandom /dev/random
```

Before doing so, it can be wise to mv the original random to somewhere else if you will need it again:

```
mv /dev/random /dev/chaos
```

After a restart, the changes will be gone, but you can set up udev rules to make it a permanent thing. See https://n0tablog.wordpress.com/2007/11/24/running-out-of-entropy-in-debian-etch/

Answer (score 1):

Later versions of udev can't rename kernel device nodes, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120272. As a workaround you can use this rule (filename could be `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-random-is-urandom.rules`):

`KERNEL=="random", RUN+="/bin/ln -sf /dev/urandom /dev/random"`

It is probably safer to use `KERNEL==random` than `KERNEL=urandom` as this version is free from any race conditions between the creation of the `random` and `urandom` device nodes. To keep both device nodes use this:

`KERNEL=="random", RUN+="/bin/mv /dev/random /dev/eerandom", RUN+="/bin/ln -s /dev/urandom /dev/random"`

Answer (score 0):

implementing @Kent 's idea, this should do it:

```
printf '#!/bin/sh\nmv /dev/random /dev/random_original\nln -s /dev/urandom /dev/random' > /etc/init.d/random_noblock.sh
chmod +x /etc/init.d/random_noblock.sh
update-rc.d random_noblock.sh defaults 100
/etc/init.d/random_noblock.sh
```